# Is there any possible ways to do model monitoring in aws without an endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a model monitoring container for an ml project in aws sagemaker. Where I'm use processing jobs for the pre and post processing and model metric part. Can I incorporate model monitoring in that; without creating an endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment. Model Monitoring is tied to SageMaker RealTime endpoints.

Comment: My project works on batch data and its not a real-time application to run live; where I don't require an endpoint. Is there any alternative methods that could be of help on attaching model monitoring piece?